# Why $pull does not work when using mongodb on node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pull

I want to put elements in and out of arrays

I created an array in user schema and add _id in the user's array whenever I add an item

And I did this with $ push

I have found that $pull is used in the mongodb documentation to remove from the array

The document was supposed to use the same as $push

but it wasn't working

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
exports.remove_list = (req, res) => {
const {item_id, user_id} = req.body

const remove_id = () => {
    return User.remove_item_list(user_id, item_id)
}

const respond = () => {
    res.json({
        message: 'remove bucket list successfully'            
    })
}

const onError = (error) => {
    res.status(409).json({
        message: error.message
    })
}

Bucket.deleteOneBy_id(item_id)
.then(remove_id)
.then(respond)
.catch(onError)
}
```

deleteOneBy_id is delete document by _id

and this is remove_item_list code

```
User.statics.remove_item_list= function(user_id, item_id){
return this.update({_id: user_id}, {$pull: {'item_list': item_id}})
}
```

this is my schema code

```
const User = new user_Schema({
email: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
password: {type:String, required:true},
item_list:{type:Array}
});
```

And the postman code I used for testing

```
    {
    "user_id":"5b122609f8d6901c244dfc76",
    "item_id":"5b14dc68cfa0732464334b2f" 
}
```

The above value is a copy of the value of _id stored in mongodb

I looked up several documents and found no problems with my $ pull

But it did not work and there seems to be a problem I do not know

If you know why, let me know

Comment: Because your schema is wrong and those will actually be `ObjectId` values. Change the schema to `item_list:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }]`. If that does not work then show the actual documents as they appear from the `mongo` shell. Not screenshots and not `console.log()` dumps, but the `mongo` shell. Since that shows us the correct data types.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for helping. 
I never thought about it Thank you again for your help and hope you have a good day :)